# Serilization Problem in WebSerice using Linq to SQL

Tags: asp.net, web-services, linq-to-sql

Iam using linq to SQl, And I have some Serilization problem,

For Example I have two tables, Locations and Maps
When Iam returning a list of locations I want also the map for the location to be returned together with the Json object that gets returned from the service,

How this issue solved in asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a serialization problem. You will have to create a query that joins both the map and location and return the final result as json string.